# When a new testing tool is purchased it should be used first by?

Tags: iseb

This question has been asked before, but it was a couple of years ago, so things could have updated now and people could have had new thoughts on the matter, I had tried to find the official definition but have so far failed my search.

When a new testing tool is purchased it should be used first by?

A) A small team to establish the best way to use the tool
B) Everyone who may eventually have some use for the tool
C) Independent Test Team
D) The managers to see what projects it should be used in

My colleague and I always thought that this was A, but in my mock exams it has been a 50/50 split between answer A and B.

People say it is **B** as the tool has already been purchased and a small team would have already found a way to use it before they purchased it.

People say it is **A** as this seems the standard, as you would find the best way of using it before giving it everyone to use. (We did this in our company, few testers tried something before general launch)

I have my exam in a week so getting clarification on this question would help me lots, as every correct answer helps :)

Comment: I guess there is an 'exam' answer, however please be aware that in the REAL world any of those answers _could_ be correct depending on circumstances.  btw those exams have limited value in the (hiring) marketplace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer should be **B** because when a new tool is purchased by the management eventually it has to be used by all the team member.

Option **A** will come on the scenario before the tool has been purchased a small team has to analyse a variety of tools for exploring the pros and cons of that tool whether this will satisfy the pain points, the tool will make our work easier, the cost of the tool, will the tool be suitable for our organisation. 
All these things will be considered in the phase Option A.

After the tool is purchased it has to be used by all the team members.

You will get the answer for this question when you read the **ISTQB Foundation level syllabus chapter 6.**

Comment: All the best!!!